# Access to the private "Nombre" variable of this ActionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing, oop

I'm trying to access the "nombre Variable of this action performed but it's private, i need it in another action performed

```
 private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   {                                           
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    FileFilterJava filtro = new FileFilterJava();
    chooser.addChoosableFileFilter((javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter) filtro);

    if (chooser.showDialog(this, "Seleccionar despliegue")== JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
     {
     if ((chooser.getSelectedFile() != null) &&(!chooser.getSelectedFile().toString().isEmpty())) 
        {
            File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            String Nombre = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
            System.out.println(Nombre);
            mimicList.add(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Mimic mimic = getMimic(mimicList.get(0));
            jTabbedPane1.add(mimic);

        }

    }
```

Comment: String `Nombre` it's not private, it's a local variable which scope is the `if` block.If you have an instance variable with that name you are  *shadowing* it. BTW variables in java starts with lower-case by convention.

Comment: thanks, but how can i do that?

Comment: @AiramMetal I've proposed a solution below. Take a look and see if it helps you solve your problem! :)

Comment: Thanks Alexis Leclerc! that was correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you're trying to make the selected file name in your `jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(...)` method available to other methods.

Simply declare a private `String` field like this:

```
private String nombre;
```

Then, assign the selected file name to that field:

```
this.nombre = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
```

Finally, you can access that field from within the same class like this:

```
String localNombre = this.nombre;
```

Hope that helps!